# How does Activity Monitor get the URLs related to a "Safari Web Content" process?

Tags: safari, command-line, activity-monitor, macos

Does anyone know how `Activity Monitor.app` gets the list of URLs that are related to a `Safari Web Content` process? Those processes show up as `com.apple.WebKit.WebContent` in `ps` output.

[image: mouse popover showing URLs in Activity Monitor]

Comment: Somewhat related AD thread: [Has anyone figured out how to identify the unique page of each separate Safari Web Content process with Safari 7/Mavericks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106866/13833)