# How to escape modal dialog in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, dialog

A certain Safari tab is asking for a username/password that I do not have.  I can click "Cancel" on the authentication dialog but it immediately pops up again.  The dialog is modal, meaning that it disables all other UI elements of the window except the minimize/resize buttons.

How can I close the problematic tab without quitting the application?

Comment: Do you get chance to hit Cmd/W immediately after clicking Cancel?

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope, the dialog pops up again too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Open Activity Monitor, look for the process corresponding to the tab and quit it.

[image]

Comment: On my system all the processes are called "Safari Web Content".

Comment: Ok, I can identify the processing using its tooltip per http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106866, but killing the process causes the page to be reloaded, starting the cycle once again.

Comment: Following on from grgarside's answer, you just need to repeatedly kill the process. Eventually Safari should give up and show a message that the page keeps crashing.

Comment: This worked for me when I selected "Force Quit" and then went to close the tab. And the rest of the Safari tabs remained open.

Answer (score -3):

1. click with the right mouse button on the page and select "back", in this way the page go back (but the modal is still there)
2. open new safari window install SafariRestore plugin
3. click on the plugin icon
4. save a new session
5. quit safari
6. open safari
7. restore the session

Comment: If modal the the whole page is frozen so 1 fails

Comment: @Mark 1 will not fail... I solved the same problem my self!